# Understanding calling convention and stack pointer

Tags: memory, assembly, x86, calling-convention

I want to understand how should I use local variables and how to pass arguments to function in x86. I read a lot of guides, and they all wrote that the first parameter should be at [ebp+8], but it isn't here :/ WHat am I missing? What am I not understanding correctly?

```
number byte "724.5289",0

.code
main PROC

mov ebx,offset number ;making so that [ebp] = '7' atm
push ebx ;I push it on stack so I can access it inside the function
call rewrite

main ENDP

rewrite PROC
push ebp     ; push ebp so we can retrieve later
mov ebp, esp ; use esp memory to retrieve parameters and 
sub esp, 8   ; allocate data for local variable 

lea ebx, [ebp-8]
lea eax, [ebp+8]  ; i think here ebp+8 should point to the same now to which ebx did 
                  ;before function, but it does not, writechar prints some garbage ascii character
call writechar
call crlf     

rewrite ENDP

END main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass a pointer as argument to `rewrite`, and then pass its address on to `writechar`. That is you take the address twice. That is one too many :)

You want `mov eax, [ebp+8]` instead of `lea eax, [ebp+8]`

Also, you need to clean up the stack after yourself, which you don't do. Furthermore, make sure your assembler automatically emits a `RET` for the `ENDP` directive, otherwise you will be in trouble. You might want to write it out explicitly.

Comment: This is just a draft, this function is not finished. What I wanted with 'lea eax, ebp+8' was to make eax point to the same character as ebp+8 currently does, and rewrite them one by one

Comment: You need the `mov` for that. As I said, `lea` takes the address  when you want the value. If it helps this is C code for what you did: `void rewrite(char* p) { writechar(&p); }`. You took the address of your argument, which is already a pointer and you really need the value.

Comment: And what do you mean with passing the address too many times? writechar doesn't overwrite the address, it just prints it, doesnt it?

Comment: Aaah, that makes sense, thanks. edit: Although it makes sense, it still prints out garbage value :(

Comment: Not sure what `writechar` is supposed to do, I assumed it was actually writing the string pointed to by `eax`. If it is instead printing the character in `eax` then you are printing the pointer hence the garbage. In that case to print the first letter of the string you will need to load that into eax such as: `mov eax, [ebp+8]; mov al, [eax]; call writechar`. This is equivalent to `writechar(*p)` in C.

Comment: Wouldn't `mov al, [eax];` interfere with address stored in eax? Writechar prints character in eax, yes.

Comment: Yes, it will interfere. But if `writechar` wants the character there you must put it there. You can always reload the pointer from `[ebp+8]` or use a different register for it, such as: `mov ebx, [ebp+8]; mov al, [ebx]; call writechar`

Comment: Thank you <3 I finally got it and succesfuly wrote atof function without any global parameters